# Python - how to create graph of variable assignment?

Tags: python

In a sample python class function, I have one or more class items that have arbitrary type and constructor signatures that all have a single return value and one or more original parameters to the function. Additionally, I have the possibility of using the output of a given member object as the input to another member object:

```
class Blah(...):
    def __init__(
    def myfunc(param1, param2... param_n):
        r1 = self.obj1(param1,...)
        ...
        r_n = self.obj_n(param1,r1,...)
```

What I need to know is, is there a way to instrument python to track edges between input and output of each invocation of a given set of tracked objects?

For example, as in the above, the result would be a graph: (param1...) -> r1, and (param1,r1...) -> r_n

The actual edge direction doesn't matter so long as the input-output relationship is consitent.

Comment: Maybe adapt a memoize decorator to your purpose - [python decorator library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary).  - maybe a cross with the Easy Dumping of function arguments decorator.  .. Your question seems a little too broad.

Comment: So, memoize will make a dictionary tracking the input and output of each of the function calls, but I think that 1) this decorator's dictionary is not accessible to userland and 2) that it is a decoration per memory object and 3) that this decoration has to be retroactively added.

Comment: You want to parse your file(s) and create the graph?

Comment: The file is a regular python source code file. I don't want to parse it, I would like to use - as much as possible - python code to instrument it or otherwise obtain this graph. I actually don't want to have to run the function if at all possible, because that exposes the code to a greater potential for error than necessary. So parsing would be best, but only if I can get it as defined by python.

Answer (score 0):

You could trace the function, and create a mapping of every function call.

An example of this is [pytorch's onnx](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html) export capability, which uses this technique. In addition, if that's not enough, you could probably resort to using the python debugger api or just instrument all items within a module by using the inspect module.

```
import inspect
inspect.getmembers(your_module, isfunction)
```

By creating a class and defining call with the kwargs convention, you can match the signature of any object or function that you wrap with it. Then, when you iterate on the members of a module, you can wrap and re-assign that member with some class instance that reads the function meta-data or dynamic type information (f.**name** or otherwise), you can then track the arguments (maintain names by some unique id generation scheme) and function names and just create a graph right out of them.